# How can I find tables, having a defined column?

Tags: sql, db2

I am using db2 and I want to find tables, having a column named "person_name".
I heard about a syscat table or something like that.

How do I work with it, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    *
from 
  syscat.columns
where
 colname = 'person_name'
```

Comment: for my DB2 version I use `sysibm.columns` instead of `syscat.columns`, it just could be another answer

Answer (score 3):

```
  select 
  tabname,
  colname,
  typename,
  length,
  scale,
  default,
  nulls,
  identity,
  genereted,
  remark,
  keyseq 
from 
  syscat.columns
```